# Creating hierarchy of files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, c#-to-vb.net, csproj

I'm trying to create hierarchy of classes in vb.net. I was able to achieve it in csharp by using
the following tags in .csproj

```
<Compile Include="ClassA.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ClassB.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Below snippet in the solution explorer would be as follows

[image: Class Hierarchy in Csharp]

I need to achieve the same in vb.net.

I'm new to vb.net. Can anybody tell me the alternative of `<DependUpon>` attribute used in .csproj equivalent in .vbproj. For some reason, this attribute seems to be ignored in the .vbproj even though it is displayed in the visualstudio2010 intellisence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Reference, My post is been answered in the below link

[Answer] (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/5a79d68e-f85d-4bbe-a818-1e107efaafc4)

Answer (score 1):

[Your question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/msbuild/thread/5a79d68e-f85d-4bbe-a818-1e107efaafc4) has been answered by [Ego](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/ego%20jiang/?ws=usercard-mini).

It's actually the same as c# (the reason being that this is MSBUILD and Visual Studio is interpreting it to give you a nice a presentation experience.

```
<Compile Include="ClassB.vb" />

    <Compile Include="ClassA.vb">

      <DependentUpon>ClassB.vb</DependentUpon>

</Compile>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the solution given by Ego. But still, the problem is persistent. Only ClassB is visible in the solution explorer. For some reason ClassA is not visible. For more reference, [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/5a79d68e-f85d-4bbe-a818-1e107efaafc4). Let me know if there is anything which needs to be done or anything which is been missing for which ClassA is not visible.